# Why isn't $P^2$ the real projective plane homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

The real projective plane $P^2$ is the set of linear subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$, with the quotient topology. So this means a set of linear subspaces $U \in P^2$ is open if and only if the points on the union of points in $U$ (regarded as points in $\mathbb{R}^3$)

So if I define the following map:

$f: P^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \times 1$ (Where $\mathbb{R}^2 \times 1$ is the subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with z coordinate = $1$.

by $f([x] = x$ where $x$ is the point in the linear subspace $[x]$ with $z$ coordinate as $1$.

This map is well defined, and is continuous because for any open set $V$ in the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is the set of linear subspace that defined by a point in $V$ and the origin. and $f^{-1}(V)$ is open if the union of those these points in the union of the linear subspace is open in $R^3$. Which shouldn't be too hard to show by showing this on the basis for the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Here I already have the fraudulent result that says there's a surjective continuous function from $P^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. And I have no idea what I am doing wrong here.

Can someone point out why the reasoning above is false?

Comment: A linear subspace may have no point with $z$-coordinate 1.

Comment: oh shoot...you are right. Then what can one do to show that P^n is a n manifold in general. I had a "proof" that P^n is locally euclidean using this map. So I guess my approach is completely wrong then...

Comment: Some interesting topological ways in which the projective plane differs from the other plane: it is nonorientable; you can embed $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ in it without edge-crossings.

Comment: So to show that it is an n-manifold, can we still use a similar "projecting map" by showing that for every linear subspace in $[x] \in P^2$, there exists a point $x \in [x]$ s.t. some coordinate of $x$ is equals to 1, and it should be easy to show that this is  true for some "neighborhood" of $[x]$, and then define a similar map above only on such a neighborhood of $[x]$?

Comment: Probably a better idea to post a new question about showing it's a manifold (first checking to see whether such a question has already been asked and answered here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $f$ function is a projection onto $\mathbb{R}^2$. However (as noted in comments) the map is not defined for points without $z=1$ coordinate. In the real projetive plane these are points with the third coordinate $0$, i.e. $[x,y,0]$. And there is no way to fix that in order to obtain a homeomorphism as I will explain soon.

What you've actually describing is very similar to [the sterographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection). Similarly the sterographic projection maps homeomorphically a sphere **without** a point to $\mathbb{R}^n$. But a sphere itself is not homeomoprhic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

This also is true for $P^n$ simply because $P^n$ can be defined as a quotient:

$$q:S^n\to P^n$$

under the antipodal points identification. In particular this implies that $P^n$ is compact (as an image of a sphere) and so it cannot be homeomorphic to an Euclidean space. And indeed, by the same argument $\mathbb{R}^m$ can't even be an image of $P^n$.